# How to get a screen capture of a .Net WinForms control programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, capture

How do you programmatically obtain a picture of a .Net control?

Comment: This is a bit too vague, try to explain what are you trying to do. No wander the down votes.

Comment: No wander?  I think the meaning is perfectly clear.  He wants to get a bitmap representation of a control.

Comment: I agree with Will. It's a simple and clear question.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I reworded the question a bit.  It's a good question and a good answer by Will.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There's a method on every control called [DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx).  You don't need to p/invoke to do this.

```
Control c = new TextBox();
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(c.Width, c.Height);
c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.ClientRectangle);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get a picture of a .NET control programmatically pretty easily using the ***DrawToBitmap*** method of the Control class starting in .NET 2.0

Here is a sample in VB

```
    Dim formImage As New Bitmap("C:\File.bmp")
    Me.DrawToBitmap(formImage, Me.Bounds)
```

And here it is in C#:

```
 Bitmap formImage = New Bitmap("C:\File.bmp")
 this.DrawToBitmap(formImage, this.Bounds)
```

Answer (score 5):

[Control.DrawToBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap) will let you draw most controls to a bitmap. This does not work with RichTextBox and some others.

If you want to capture these, or a control that has one of them, then you need to do PInvoke like described in this CodeProject article: [Image Capture](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/imagecapture.aspx)

Take care that some of these methods will capture whatever is on the screen, so if you have another window covering your control you will get that instead.

Comment: For WebBrowser, I just cast to Control and call it there.  I've done it and know it works.  Not sure about RichTextBox

Answer (score 3):

For WinForms controls that support it, there is a method in the System.Windows.Forms.Control class:

```
public void DrawToBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle targetBounds);
```

This does not work with all controls, however. Third party component vendors have more comprehensive solutions.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to do it for an entire `Form`, not just the Client area (which doesn't have the title bar and other dressing)

```
        Rectangle r = this.Bounds;
        r.Offset(-r.X,-r.Y);
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(r.Width,r.Height);
        this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, r);
        Clipboard.SetImage(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's not on the control you're trying to do, you can usually cast it to the base Control class and call the DrawToBitmap method there.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Panel1.Dock = DockStyle.None ' If Panel Dockstyle is in Fill mode
Panel1.Width = 5000  ' Original Size without scrollbar
Panel1.Height = 5000 ' Original Size without scrollbar

Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height)
Me.Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height))
'Me.Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, Panel1.ClientRectangle)
bmp.Save("C:\panel.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

Panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

**Note:** Its working fine