# C# convert XtraGrid to Image

Tags: c#, export, devexpress, xtragrid

I want to export a XtraGrid as an image.
Pratically i need something like XtraChart.ExportToImage() but for the XtraGrid.
Is there a method to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if this helps you: http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q107282.aspx

Comment: Thanks for help, but i need to export the xtragrid as image not xls because i have to insert it into a pdf file (using itextsharp library). Maybe there's something more easy to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows every control can be written to a bitmap using the [Control.DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Method. Even if the control is hidden, its possible to capture it as a bitmap.

[How to get a screen capture of a .Net WinForms control programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266116/how-to-get-a-screen-capture-of-a-net-control-programmatically)

Comment: It works very well but when i use this method for the DevExpress.XtraEditors.PanelControl, in the generated image the panel return to its default color (grey), but in the code i've change it to white. I think there's something wrong during conversion because on debugging i've verified the changing of the property "BackColor" of my panel: the change happens and the backcolor is white until the conversion, but in the image the panel is grey. What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: hmm, no idea, I have tried this on pretty complex user controls never had this problem. You can actually see the panel as white in UI?

Comment: I use the panel to group some elements (text, images), then i can save it (the panel) as a bitmap with Control.DrawToBitmap method. So, my panel is instantiated dinamically and i can't see it by designer. The strange thing is that the backcolor is white before and after the call "myPanel.DrawToBitmap".
Now, to resolve, i've insert a PictureBox Control (in background with the size of the panel) with white backcolor and it works. Very strange problem.